# error when echo date() format?

Tags: php

I have a datetime with format: 2012-03-30 11:47:58

```
$datetime = '2012-03-30 11:47:58';
$publishdate = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $datetime );
```

When I `echo $publishdate` is result is `'01/01/1970 07:33:32'` , How to fix it

Comment: `date` accepts timestamp as 2nd argument, not a formatted date.

Answer (score 1):

```
$publishdate = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($datetime) );
```

Or using `DateTime`

```
$date = new DateTime($datetime);
$publishdate = $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work, note the call to `strtotime()`, it turns the datestring into a date so you can format it:

```
$datetime = '2012-03-30 11:47:58';
$publishdate = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($datetime) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$datetime = '2012-03-30 11:47:58';
$timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
$publishdate = date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
```

First, convert your date and time to timestamp with `strtotime()` method, then format again with `date()` function.